# Making a Javascript array of multiple CSS classes assigned to an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coldfusion, input

MY javascript: Updated Again.

```
$('.calc').change(function () {
    var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(',');

    $.each(classArray, function () {
        alert(classArray);
    });
});
```

And the input:

```
<input type="text" class="calc R#r# C#i#" />
```

The pound signs are variables, I'm using ColdFusion.

What I need to be able to do is successfully take each class and place them in an array. That way I can use that to do the required calculations for the entire table.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the class attribute value, using space as the separator:

```
$('.calc').change(function(){
  var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
});
```

**Edit:** I think that you want to do this.

```
$('.calc').change(function(){
  var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');

  $.each(classArray, function(){
    alert(this);
  });
});
```

Try [this](http://jsbin.com/ipika/edit) running example.

Comment: That got me to return 3 objects, but all of which were calc R1 C1. What I need to display is: calc in it's own box, R1 in it's own box, and C1 in it's own box.

Comment: Yeah it did. Thanks! I had my other one left in the code and it was breaking, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

CMS' answer definitely works for me. I doubt this is a browser issue but I suppose that's a possibility?